# Lua C - Is there a way to keep a value in C, but still have it not garbage collected?

Tags: lua, luac, lua-c++-connection

I am creating a thread in lua c, but i want to keep it just in C, without making it a variable in the environment/etc. But when i throw away the thread value that gets pushed by lua_newthread, it gets garbace collected shortly after, and so becomes useless.
In this thread i want to run arbitrary lua code passed by the user, allowing them to use the exclusive functions/variables that are isolated from other threads.

Is there a way to mark a thread/userdata/table value as non-garbage-collectable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible.
You can add a call to gc_mark with your TValue's gcobj as an argument into gc_markroots.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to reference it somewhere or disable GC.
Use `lua_ref` to reference is in mostly-hidden place: registry. (`debug.getregistry()`)

Comment: While this is a good answer that would work in many cases - it probably would not for me... I want other threads to have access to the registry too, via debug.getregistry.

Comment: Do you mean coroutine-like threads or separate lua states?

Comment: lua_newthread. Not a separate global state but a separate lua state. This is what coroutines use internally, so yes, coroutine-like threads. It would be nearly impossible for me to have different global states if i didnt use lualanes or other stuff.